# Objective-c JSONModel

Tags: objective-c, json, linker-errors

I followed the instruction to instal JSONModel to my project. However, I am having an issue with Apple Mach - O Linker Error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JSONModel+CoreData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSManagedObject_$_JSONModel in JSONModel+CoreData.o
      objc-class-ref in JSONModel+CoreData.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added SystemConfiguration.framework as well.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what are your build settings?

Comment: Does the library contain the `x86_64` arch (use `lipo` to find out)?

Answer (score 0):

Add `CoreData.framework` to your target.

[image]